# Lista de imagens flutter

Tags: array, flutter, dart

No meu app em flutter eu quero exibir imagens, e essas imagens estarão agrupadas por categorias/álbuns. Essas imagens são trazidas na forma de um array, nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a minha atual função para trazer essas imagens

```
class ImagensApiProvider {
  Future<List<Imagens>> imagens() async {
    final response = await Dio().get(
      ApplicationConsts.BASE_API_URI + 'images/' + '3/' + '20',
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsed = response.data.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      return parsed.map<Imagens>((json) => Imagens.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Falha ao carregar Imagens');
    }
  }
}
```

O '/3' e '20' são respectivamente o id do usuário e o id do álbum (isso eu resolvo depois).

O fato é que me deparei com o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no response.data eu recebo o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu resolvo isso?

Desde já, agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Se a minha resposta te ajudou ou até mesmo resolveu seu problema, por favor marque-a como aceita, isso é claro, caso não esteja esperando outras respostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já recebe uma lista de `Strings`, não tem porque transformar ela em um Map, trabalhe direto nela:

Subistitua isso

```
final parsed = response.data.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
return parsed.map<Imagens>((json) => Imagens.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

por isso

```
return response.data.map<Imagens>((json) => Imagens.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

Comment: agora to recebendo esse erro _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: Provavelmente teu método `fromJson()` está esperando receber um `Map<String, dynamic>`, faça as alterações nele, pois agora ele vai receber uma String diretamente.